# How to save an alias when selecting an entry in xe:dominoViewValuePicker

Tags: javascript, xml, xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

When I create a new document I want the users to able to select one customer from a list of 20.000 customers. I first tried to use the simpleValuePicker but I think the view was to big for that as I got some errors.  so I choosed to go with the dominoViewValuePicker which seem to be fast and it also allow searching.

The problem I have is that when the user selected a customer I want the value stored to be the unid (or some other unique value) of the customer document and not the value the user sees when selecting. The user should never see the unid , not in the dialog and not in the selection field.

```
<xe:djextListTextBox id="djextListTextBox5" value="#{actDoc.Customer}"></xe:djextListTextBox>
<xe:valuePicker id="valuePicker9" for="djextListTextBox5" dojoType="extlib.dijit.PickerListSearch" pickerText="Select Customer" dialogTitle="Select Customer">
    <xe:this.dataProvider>
        <xe:dominoViewValuePicker viewName="customers"></xe:dominoViewValuePicker>
    </xe:this.dataProvider>
</xe:valuePicker>
```

[image]

How can I accomplish this so that when user select a customer using the dominoViewValuePicker another value than what the user sees is stored in the document when it is saved.

Comment: You might want to be careful with this approach. Picking 20000 values from essentially a popup isn't good user interaction. Could you redesign your flow to first pick a customer in a whole page dialog and then call the following page using the id as parameter (or as session variable). This way you are free to implement better search UI capabilities instead of being limited that the Value Picker does (e.g. introduce filtering / sorting / last used values / favorites etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The viewValuePicker always stores the value in the first column of the view. You can change the display value using the labelColumn property. You can then use displayLabel="true" to show the label on the DojoListTextBox.